# Capistrano: Some tasks are fired but has no output and does nothing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, migration, capistrano

I'm trying to use Capistrano (3.6) to deploy my app, but some tasks doesn't works and return just nothing.

When I execute `cap production deploy` the release is correctly downloaded from my git server, the bundle install works, and files are linked. But some tasks seems to be skipped like "deploy:migrate".

I've tried to debug by creating these two tasks to see what happening during the deployment:

```
namespace :deploy do
  before :migrate, :debug do
    puts "BEFORE"
  end

  after :migrate, :debug do
    puts "AFTER"
  end
end
```

And i saw my tasks correctly hooked just after bundle install:

```
00:03 bundler:install
      01 ~/.rvm/bin/rvm 2.3.0 do bundle install --path /home/myuser/app/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --qui…
    ✔ 01 myuser@myhost 2.380s
BEFORE
AFTER
00:05 deploy:symlink:release
```

But as you can see, nothing happens between BEFORE and AFTER, However i've pending migrations.

And if i run the task alone `cap production deploy:migrate` there is no output and nothing happens.

When I run the command directly on the remote host `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails db:migrate` it's ok !

This the same behavior for some other tasks like puma:x, deploy:compile_asset, etc...

**My Environment**

I use RVM (single user) with ruby 2.3.0 (both side)
My app is a Rails 5 (api only)

**In my Gemfile**

```
gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.6.0'
gem 'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.1'
gem 'capistrano-rvm', '~> 0.1.1'
gem 'capistrano3-puma', github: "seuros/capistrano-puma"
```

**In my Capfile**

```
require 'capistrano/rvm'
require 'capistrano/rails'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/puma'
require 'capistrano/puma/nginx'
```

**My deploy.rb**

```
set :rvm_ruby_version, '2.3.0'

set :application, 'myapp'
set :repo_url, 'git@gitlab.mydomain.com:me/myapp.git'
set :deploy_to, '/home/myuser/app'

append :linked_files, 'config/database.yml', 'config/secrets.yml'
append :linked_dirs, 'log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets'

set :nginx_config_name, 'myapp'
set :nginx_server_name, 'myapp.mydomain.com'
```

**My production.rb**

```
server 'myhost', user: 'myuser', roles: %(app web db)

set :rails_env, 'production'
```

Thank for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you've made a typo in your `production.rb`. If you run `cap production doctor` it will alert you to the problem.

Basically you have written `%(app web db)` when you meant `%w(app web db)`.

See also this answer: [Rails assets aren't compiling after Capistrano deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35718268/rails-assets-arent-compiling-after-capistrano-deployment/35732693#35732693)

Comment: Oh my god you're right, didn't saw this typo, that's embarrassing, I feel so noob! Thank you very much for your help and for this great and helpful tool!